# Dynamic mapping in Dataweave

Tags: dynamic, mule, dataweave

I'm trying to map a column name dynamically in Dataweave using the contents of a flow variable. The static version of what I'm trying to achieve looks something like:

```
payload map ((payload01 , indexOfPayload01) -> {
    COLUMNA: payload01.INPUTA
})
```

Now the part that I need to be dynamic is `INPUTA` - I need the `A` to be derived from a flow variable that is set prior to the Dataweave component. I've tried something like:

```
payload map ((payload01 , indexOfPayload01) -> {
    COLUMNA: payload01.INPUT#flowVars['varName']
})
```

But I'm getting a `com.mulesoft.weave.grammar.InvalidNamespacePrefixException` error.

Is this possible to achieve in Dataweave? Can't seem to find any relevant docs describing how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use it like below. Note the parenthesis around key which is very important because () tells DataWeave to first execute script inside it and then use the result as the value for outside expression.

```
    payload map ((payload01 , indexOfPayload01) -> {
    COLUMNA: payload01[('INPUT' ++ flowVars.varName)]
})
```

Let me know that doesn't work.

I see your key name is COLUMNA, you can also append varName to key by using ().

Comment: This worked - thanks very much! Had to make a small correction, there's an unused `)` at the end of your mapping. I changed it to: `COLUMNA: payload01[('INPUT' ++ flowVars.varName)]`

Comment: Oh, yes. Initially I wrapped all content of [] in parenthesis but later removed it as its not needed, must have forgot the end one. Corrected the answer. Glad it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Try to access flowVar just like MEL way: `#[flowVars.varName]`, donot prefix with `payload01`

Comment: This doesn't work - what I'm trying to do is map to a column, `INPUTA`, from my inbound payload, the issue is that the `A` part could change dependent on circumstances so rather than writing a load of different Dataweave transformers and routing based on a variable I'd prefer to make a single transformer where the mapping is dynamic. I need to map to... `payload01.INPUT[Dynamic Text Here - from Variable]`

Answer (score 0):

From Dataweave you have to access the flowvars or session vars as given below.
flowVars.varName
sessionVars.varName

You can use various Dataweave operators to form final field names or value.
Understanding Dataweave Operators is crucial to to make best use of Dataweave component. Please go through the link below for a understanding of Dataweave operators.

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/dataweave-operators